# Triple integral boundaries

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $W\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded by the planes $y+z=2, 2x=y, x=0, z=0$, what are the boundaries of $\int\int\int_W x dV$?

How can I find the boundaries if I take $dV$ as $dydxdz$, $dxdzdy$ and $dzdydx$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A picture can help. $W$ is the tetrahedron with the grey plane as its base.

[image]

The three sets of boundaries:

$$\int_{y=0}^{2} \int_{x=0}^{y/2} \int_{z=0}^{2-y} {x\;dy\;dx\;dz} \\
\int_{x=0}^{1} \int_{z=0}^{2-2x} \int_{y=2x}^{2-z} {x\;dx\;dz\;dy} \\
\int_{z=0}^{2} \int_{y=0}^{2-z} \int_{x=0}^{y/2} {x\;dz\;dy\;dx}.$$
The reasoning for the first one, for example:

\begin{eqnarray*}
y &:& \text{over the whole region, $y$ has a min of $0$ and max of $2$} \\
x &:& \text{given $y$, then $x$ has a min of $0$ and max of $y/2$} \\
z &:& \text{given $y,x$, then $z$ has a min of $0$ and max of $2-y$ (regardless of $x$).} \\
\end{eqnarray*}